# how to make the new add button running

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys im trying to make a dynamic design for adding students in a class with a button add on the 10th row ![enter image description here][1]

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=4099710263250&set=a.1210298669766.32621.1597725369&type=3&theater

i can append a new row with a button on it but when i click the new button the click function did not respond and i still need to click the add button on the 10th row to add new one.

here is the code.

```
         <table>
            <th colspan="4"><h2>Boys</h2></th>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_lname1" class="input">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_mname1" class="input">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_fname1" class="input">
              </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_lname2" class="input">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_mname2" class="input">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_fname2" class="input" >
              </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_lname3" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_mname3" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_fname3" class="input" >
              </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_lname4" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_mname4" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_fname4" class="input" >
              </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_lname5" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_mname5" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_fname5" class="input" >
              </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_lname6" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_mname6" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_fname6" class="input" >
              </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_lname7" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_mname7" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_fname7" class="input" >
              </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_lname8" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_mname8" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_fname8" class="input" >
              </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_lname9" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_mname9" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_fname9" class="input" >
              </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_lname10" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_mname10" class="input" >
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="bstudnt_fname10" class="input" >

                <input type="button" id="" name="add_bstudent" class="button add-        bstudent" value="+">
              </td>  
            </tr>              
          </table>
```

JS....

```
$('.add-bstudent').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().after("<tr><td><label>Name:</label></td><td>  <input type='text' name='bstudnt_lname10' class='input' placeholder='Last Name'></td><td><input type='text' name='bstudnt_mname10' class='input' placeholder='Middle Name'></td><td><input type='text' name='bstudnt_fname10' class='input' placeholder='First Name'> <input type='button' id='' name='add_bstudent' class='button add-bstudent' value='+'></td></tr>");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the click() function to register the event, it will only register the event on objects returned by the selector at that moment. If you create an object after the fact, it won't bind to the event. Use the on() function and give it your selector: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Example:

`$('#container').on('click', '.add-bstudent', function(event) { ... });`

Comment: @undefined good example, however I would recommend giving the initial $ function a container DOM element other than document, so that the event doesn't have to bubble all the way through the DOM. It also contains the event binding within that container in case you want different functionality somewhere else in the page.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that you do not have a button with  class by name of `$('.add-bstudent')`.
It's the name attribute for the button..
Also consider delegating the  event by using the .on() so that the event is attached when the element is available

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('.add-bstudent').click(function () {
        $(this).parent('table').append("<tr><td><label>Name:</label></td><td>  <input type='text' name='bstudnt_lname10' class='input' placeholder='Last Name'></td><td><input type='text' name='bstudnt_mname10' class='input' placeholder='Middle Name'></td><td><input type='text' name='bstudnt_fname10' class='input' placeholder='First Name'> <input type='button' id='' name='add_bstudent' class='button add-bstudent' value='+'></td></tr>");
    });
```